# PHP instantiate dynamic namespaced class

Tags: php

I have a class that I need to instantiate based on a variable passed from a form. The form either passes the string `Product` or `Sku` to my PHP script. The fully qualified class that needs to be instantiated is either:

```
$obj = new MyNameSpace\Product();
```

Or

```
$obj = new MyNameSpace\Sku();
```

I can't figure out how to properly create this namespace on the fly. I've tried the following:

```
$obj = new "MyNameSpace\\".$class();
```

Which throws this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"MyNameSpace\\"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)
```

I've read other questions and answers that say to escape the slash in order to make it a literal slash, but even that does not seem to be working for me. For example:

```
$class = "Product";
$string = "MyNameSpace\\".$class;
echo $string;
```

`$string` prints as `MyNameSpace\\Product` instead of `MyNameSpace\Product`. What am I missing here?

Comment: That worked, thank you! Please add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new` keyword supports only two syntaxes:

```
new ClassNameLiteral;
```

or

```
new $ClassNameString;
```

So you'll have to assemble your classname with namespace prefix beforehand:

```
$cn = "ns\\$class";
$obj = new $cn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
$class_name = 'Namespace\Class';
$instance = new $class_name;
```